# Is there a C++ equivalent of the variable discard '_' in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, arduino-c++, equivalent

In C#, there's a convenient feature using the underscore `_` as a discard variable when one wants to explicitly ignore the result of an operation.

I'm currently looking for an equivalent feature or workaround in C++ that would allow me to discard specific values or save memory allocation when retrieving multiple values from a function.

**Example**:

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
void readValues(float& temperature, float& humidity, float& dewpoint, float& tempTrend, float& humTrend) {
    // Some operation to retrieve values
}
```

If I only need to know the temperature, and I do not have a temperature-specific function, how can I discard the other values in the most memory-efficient way?

Or any other approach that could help in conserving memory space when ignoring certain return values from functions in an Arduino/ESP32 environment?

**What I'm doing now:**

```
float temperature;
float discard;

readValues(temperature, discard, discard, discard, discard);
```

**What I tried:**

```
float temperature;
readValeus(temperature, null_ptr, null_ptr, null_ptr, null_ptr);
```

```
float temperature;
readValues(temperature, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Thank you for any insights or suggestions!

Comment: I recommend avoiding **out parameters**, instead use **return values**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to do what you want.
There is no direct equivalent to the `discard` keyword though.

Firstly, I wouldn't worry about being memory-efficient in this case.
Even if you always returned all values, unused values and their creation may be optimized away.

Also, output parameters are typically frowned upon in C++. (see [F.20: For “out” output values, prefer return values to output parameters](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-out)) You can pack things into a `struct` and then simply use the parts of it that you're interested in. Anyhow, here are some possible solutions:

#### (1) Function overloading

```cpp
void readValues(float& temperature, float& humidity, float& dewpoint);
void readValues(float& temperature, float& humidity);
```

The second overload makes `dewpoint` effectively an optional parameter.

#### (2) Pointers and default parameters

```cpp
void readValues(float& temperature, float& humidity, float* dewpoint = nullptr);
// ...
readValues(t, h);     // don't provide dewpoint
readValues(t, h, &d); // provide dewpoint
```

#### (3) Avoid output parameters

This is my personal favorite.

```cpp
struct Weather {
    float temperature;
    float humidity;
    float dewpoint;
};

Weather readValues();

// ...
Weather w = readValues();
auto [t, h, d] = readValues();
auto [t, h, _] = readValues();
```

#### (4) `[[maybe_unused]]`

```
void readValues(float& temperature, float& humidity, float& dewpoint);
// ...

float t, h;
[[maybe_unused]] float _;
readValues(t, h, _);
```

You still have to provide an extra argument, but `[[maybe_unused]]` expresses intent clearly and suppresses warnings about unused variables, if any.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Honestly I would prefer to avoid modifying the function, as it is part of a library.

Comment: @TimoFran Then create a simple wrapper around it: `Weather readValues() { Weather w; readValues(w.temperature, w.humidity, w.dewpoint); return w; }`

Comment: Additionally the identifier `_` will have special behavior in C++26 so that it can be used multiple times for discarded variables in the same scope and so that `[[maybe_unused]]` won't be necessary anymore when using it.

Comment: There is also [`std::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore).  And C++26 may have [a nice placeholder with no name](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2169r0.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

It is trivial to implement some sort of `_` surrogate providing object to store output value and doing nothing with it.

```
void readValues(float& temperature, float& humidity, float& dewpoint, float& tempTrend, int& counter) {
    // Some operation to retrieve values
}

class t_Discarder final
{
    public: template<typename x_Object>
    /* IMPLICIT */ operator x_Object &(void) const
    {
        static x_Object s_object{};
        return s_object;
    }
};

t_Discarder _{};

int main()
{
    float temperature{};
    readValues(temperature, _, _, _, _);
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/dP35Ms8hd)

However is it certainly not a good practice. In production code it would be better to supply properly named arguments and to explicitly mark them as unused or to invent a better query interface that does not require supplying so many arguments every time with most of them being discarded.